# bash: composer.phar: command not found

Tags: php, composer-php

I checked all topic and not anyone help me.

```
sudo curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

now

```
mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

I check:

```
[root@live7263 ~]# cd /usr/local/bin/
[root@live7263 bin]# ls
composer
[root@live7263 bin]# composer list
Options:
  -h, --help                     Display help for the given command. When no command is given display help for the list command
  -q, --quiet                    Do not output any message
  -V, --version                  Display this application version
..............
```

and now I try from user level:

```
[feed@live7263 public_html]$ composer require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet
bash: composer: command not found
[feed@live7263 public_html]$ /usr/local/bin/composer.phar require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet
bash: composer: command not found
[feed@live7263 public_html]$ /usr/local/bin/composer require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet
bash: composer: command not found
[feed@live7263 public_html]$ composer install
bash: composer: command not found
```

CodeIgniter 3.  config.php

```
/* Composer Auto Loading */
$config['composer_autoload'] = 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

file `composer.json` created in root app (public_html)

Comment: `public_html` is the location where you deploy the application to (and `vendor` as well as the roots project files must not be publicly accessible), not where you run composer. Compare with the CodeIgniter documentation. And why do you run composer on the remote host?

Answer (score 0):

If someone in the future will be bothered with this and uses CloudLinux this is temporary solution.

```
Disable user CloudLinux CageFS
```

Comment: Even this may solve your issue, I wouldn't give this as a recommended solution. For the web-user you want to benefit from the CageFS, so you just don't disable it. Instead execute Composer by following the Composer manual and invoke composer.phar as outlined (`php composer.phar` in principle) and even better don't run it on the remote system. Understand the reason why it does not work when CageFS is enabled.

Comment: yes, you have right. I update my answear and add notice.